# mfc event doesn't get called while afxMessageBox is open

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC event. 
I declare it like this:
const UINT WM_SECEVENT = RegisterWindowMessage(_T("My Event"));
I raise the event by:
::PostThreadMessageA(dwCurThreadId, WM_SECEVENT, (WPARAM)pMsgParam,0);
In my MessageMap, I wrote:
ON_REGISTERED_THREAD_MESSAGE(WM_SECEVENT, OnThreadSecEvent);

Everything works fine, when WM_SECEVENT is raised, OnThreadSecEvent starts to run.
The problem is, that I also have a yes/no afxMessageBox. While the afxMessageBox is running, my program don't "catch" the event, and OnThreadSecEvent is not getting called.
How can I fix that problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does posting to a window in the thread instead of to the thread message queue itself work for your purposes?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183116

> Rather than using PostThreadMessage to post messages to a UI thread, use PostMessage to post messages to a window owned by that thread. Since messages directed to a window can be dispatched by a secondary message loop, the messages is still handled properly, even when the thread is not running in its primary message loop.